# Bukkit - Send data back to people connected through RCON

Tags: bukkit

I have a NodeJS / SocketIO app which connects to my Minecraft server through RCON protocol and it works perfectly, keep the connection open and listens for any kind of data which is retrieved.

Example, if I type a command which isn't available, it will respond with a message.

Now I'm trying to whenever any player on the Minecraft server chats, my Bukkit plugin will take that message and send it through to any connected on RCON.

This is part of my Bukkit plugin which fires when the player chats.

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat( AsyncPlayerChatEvent e ) {
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Test 1");
        this.getLogger().info("Test 2");
        Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Test 3");
        this.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Test 4");
    }
```

The messages are recorded in the server log, though I do not get anything back through the rcon protocol.

Comment: If you still need this question answered, here's a tip: try adding some more useful information. Like the part of your plugin that actually sends the messages through RCON.

Comment: RCON used by minecraft does not have a mechanism to send messages back after the initial packets

Answer (score 1):

RCON used by minecraft does not have a mechanism to send messages back after the initial packets. If you need a mechanism like this, you need to invent your own protocol, or make a command that returns the last chat log if it's executed.

To make this command, we can simple make a `Queue<String>` where we are putting our messages (like chat) into.

```java
final Queue<String> messages = new ArrayDeque<>(64);
public void insertMessage(String message) {
    synchronized (messages) {
        messages.add(message);
        if (messages.size() == 64) // full
            messages.remove();
    }
}
```

We can then hook up this method to our chat event:

```java
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.MONITOR,ignoreCancelled=true)
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent evt) {
    insertMessage("[CHAT] " + evt.getPlayer() + " : " + evt.getMessage());
}
```

Then we only need to make a command to read out our messages list, this is easy to make:

```java
private String getMessage() {
    synchronized (messages) {
        return messages.poll();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(!cmd.testPermissions()) {
        return true;
    }
    String message;
    while((message = getMessage()) != null) {
        sender.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

This allows you to get the server log from rcon by just typing in a command or making your client application so that it executes this command every second or so.